# Where do public policy questions related to biology go?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

## Preface

This question is mostly copied from a [similar one](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4093/where-do-public-policy-questions-related-to-biology-go?noredirect=1#comment6147_4093) inside Biology Meta Stack Exchange.  It has been mostly copied here to reach a wider Meta audience in the hope that a proper Stack Echange for the linked Biology Stack Exchange question will be found.

## Background

I asked [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/93642/why-are-masks-still-required-for-covid-19-even-after-a-vaccine-is-produced?noredirect=1) on biology stack exchange to get the scientific reason behind Massachusetts' reopening policy of requiring masks even with a vaccine.

I thought I made sense to ask on Biology Stack Exchange, because there is a higher likelihood that is the place where people are knowledgeable about virology could readily provide a relatively credible epidemiological reason behind the policy. I would not expect the same from Politics.SE.

That said....I can see how it might be off topic in Biology.SE. But I am just not sure which stack exchange to ask the question at this point.

## Question

Where do biologically related public policy questions belong?

Comment: Your question on biology seemed more medical than political. I'm fairly certain that it would be off-topic on your best bet of [medicalsciences.se] because it's regarding a still-unfolding question in which many many issues are not yet resolved (the same would go for [skeptics.se]). That being said, you can read-up their help center and try to formulate an on-topic question regarding this.